# How is this backup properly executed on linux, via rsync or copy?

Tags: backup

How is this backup properly executed on linux, via `rsync` or `cp`?

For example, I have two different NvMe SSD disks and I want to make a backup each night to copy `directory1` with all its content to another SSD disk, and of course delete its previous backup.

What would be the proper backup for this? `rsync` or normal `cp`? Does anyone have any proper scripts for this?

Comment: I'd suggest you consider using `rsnapshot`, which is built on top of `rsync` and can allow you to maintain GFS (grandfather-father-son) backups.

Comment: If you want to delete the old backup, just `rsync --delete` over it.

Comment: is this command good ?    rsync -av --delete /Directory1/ /Directory2/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to mirror the two directories, rather than maintain a backup with multiple restore points.  If that is the case, you can do this easily with rsync.  Here is an example:

```
rsync -avH --progress --inplace --delete /path/to/original /path/to/copy
```

Without `--delete` rsync will just copy files, and not remove any files that are on `copy` but not on `original`